# Refactor fields missing fields after join

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, fields-attributes

I just joined two attribute tables successfully with the join function in Layer Properties.

Two new fields have appeared in my original table.

I saved the table.

However these two fields don't show up when I open Refactor fields.

Therefore I have to "save as" the table to a new table with a different name. Then the two new fields do show up.

Is this a bug, or is this normal?

Could it be changed?

Comment: Can you should screen shot of your attribute fields before and after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's normal**.

The **Refactor fields** tool only reads the fields that are saved in the shapefile. Joining layers does not save the fields into the shapefile which is why you need to save it as another to include those joined fields.

The only way to change this behavour is to edit the source code of the tool to include reading the joined fields.

---

*Another example is the **Table Manager** plugin.*